# US Visa/Greencard renewal with UK passport renewal?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, uk-citizens, us-residents

I am in the US with a green card, the visa for which is in my UK passport that expires at the end of April, while my green card itself expires in May.

I have the CR1 visa in my soon-to-be-old UK passport - do I need to get this updated or changed anywhere to go in my new passport, or will I need to carry both passports when I travel?

Also, will the passport renewal affect my green card renewal at all? When my green card expires, I will have been married for more than 2 years so be able to get the change from CR1 to IR1. I noticed this is the form i-751, which apparently costs $595 to file - I don't have this money right now; what happens if I renew without filing I-751? Can I do it later to switch to IR1 or does it have to be on renewing the card? I need to know if getting this money together is a priority so I can put it aside from my tax return if necessary.

Comment: The immigrant visa became void the moment you entered the US with it (immigrant visas are single-use). However, the immigrant visa turned into an I-551 (green card) valid for 1 year from the date of entry. Are you still trying to use that because you have not received the plastic green card yet?

Comment: No, I have the card; I just wasn't aware that I didn't need the visa any more then and was wondering what would happen when my passport was renewed.

Comment: Why not the I-751, as it seems that it costs $540 to renew the green card ($455 application fee and an $85 biometrics fee)?

Comment: So if I do I-751, I don't need to do the normal card renewal? Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @user5416: No. You can't apply for a "renewal" of your 2-year green card, because you are a conditional permanent resident whose status only lasts 2 years. You have to apply for Removal of Conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immigrant visa is no longer relevant. The immigrant visa is single-use and became invalid the moment you entered the US. (The immigrant visa does turn into an I-551 (green card) valid for one year from the date of entry, for you to use before you get the plastic green card; however, that is no longer needed as you already have the plastic green card.)

As a permanent resident, you are not required to have a passport, and whether and when you renew your passport are independent of your permanent resident status.

As a conditional permanent resident, you must apply for Removal of Conditions (ROC) with I-751 before your 2-year conditional permanent resident status expires. You do not apply for a "renewal" of the card with I-90. Normally, if you remain married with your spouse, you and your spouse apply for ROC jointly, and you must file within the 90-day period before your 2-year card's expiration date (which should be 2 years after your entry). You may also apply for ROC yourself on the basis of divorce, or abuse from your spouse, or your spouse's death, in which case you can file it any time (even if more than 90 days before the 2 years ends).

The fee for I-751 is $680 for one person (including the biometrics fee). You must file for Removal of Conditions on time; late filings are only accepted with a good reason.